# Does Mongo have disappearing/phantom writes

Tags: mongodb

I have heard that Mongo has something like phantom writes.  For example, if I have a web request with the following db commands in a single unit of work:

a) update comments in article
b) update article attributes
c) update users comment_field

Questions:

1. Is it possible that only a and c execute, and b fails or never gets to the database?
2. Is it possible that only a and b execute, and c fails or never gets to the database?

Where can I read some more in regards to this, or is it just a myth?

Comment: I'm not a Mongo person, but per their docs atomicity is only guaranteed within a single document.  If you have operations on multiple documents one set can fail and another can succeed.

Comment: Lack of transactions and lack of consistency are two of the things that separate NoSQL solutions from RDBMS - it's a lot faster to write with high concurrency if you have looser controls on the data.

Comment: Would it be inappropriate for me to throw in an observation along the lines of "Who needs consistency, [MongoDB is web scale](http://mongodb-is-web-scale.com/)!"?

Comment: Ha ha...great video.  I wasn't aware that data is not written into the database just put in a "queue"-ish. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my question, in case people come across it:

1) Yes, it is possible for A, and C to be committed and B to fail.  Atomicity only exists on documents in MongoDB.
2) Yes, this is possible as well.

See more for reading here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/